# What is the meaning of 'The institution of marriage was established, although symbols of primitive practices survived. '?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

[image]

Comment: All sentences following the "primitive" sentence list those practices: siblings marrying, one wife with two husbands, etc.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin What is institution of marriage?

Comment: I agree with  @Yosef Baskin . However can you please explain the precise nature of the question. Are you asking about the vocabulary? the grammatical structure? What part do you not understand?

Comment: @chasly supports Monica I don't know what this sentence Trying to convey

Comment: The institution of marriage is the common practice around the world of a wedding and an exclusive relationship that the society respects. Not incest, maybe two wives but not husbands.

Comment: I have answered. Does that help?

Comment: @chasly - supports Monica Can you please elaborate whole sentence word by word.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin institution of marriage(rules and regulations of marriage) was established though people practice primitive practices such as multi marriage and the like. Am I right? And also here, symbols of primitive practices means old tradition?

Comment: @ketan pendharkar - The problem is that I don't know why the word "symbols" is used. Why not just say *"The institution of marriage was established, although primitive practices survived."*?  To know why the author speaks of symbols, we need to now who these people are. I imagine they are gods and heroes, in which case it makes more sense to say that the *stories* survive.  Maybe the author was careless with the phraseology.

Comment: This question calls for a subject-matter clarification of one particular text; it is not about English language and usage.

Answer (score 1):

> What is institution of marriage?

Marriage is described as an institution. When we get married, there is a ceremony. However the ceremony lasts only for a short time. The marriage itself is expected to last for years and is thus called an institution (a culturally approved relationship).

> **Definition of institution**
>
> c: a significant practice, relationship, or organization in a society
> or culture 
> the institution of marriage
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/institution

(cross-posted with a comment by @Yosef Baskin, saying the same thing)

Comment: “Marriage is a friendship recognized by the police.” (attr. R.L.S.)

Comment: institution of marriage(rules and regulations of marriage) was established though people practice primitive practices such as multi marriage and the like. Am I right?     And also   here, symbols of primitive practices means old tradition?

Comment: @Conrado - :-) Who is R.L.S? - G.B. Shaw's brother Roy Lionel?

Comment: @ketan pendharkar - Yes that sounds right.  I don't know anything about Hinduism so I can't answer definitively.

Comment: No, He was a Scottish novelist and poet: [Robert Lewis Stevenson.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Louis_Stevenson)

Comment: Marriage is an institution, and who wants to live in an institution? (attr. Groucho Marx)

Comment: @Conrado - RLS was born with that middle name (and another, Balfour), but is much better known as Robert **Louis** Stevenson.

Comment: @Michael Harvey - Since we are nit-picking, he wasn't *born* with that name (in those days they wouldn't have known whether he was going to be a boy or a girl). He was however *christened*  Robert Lewis Balfour Stevenson!

Comment: @ketan pendharkar - Apologies that we have gone off-track by discussing and joking about R. L. Stevenson. Do you now understand the sentence you asked about? Or do you need more information?

Comment: @chasly - supports Monica My understanding: They established rules and regulations of marriage, but instead following this rules, they follow primitive practices which is mentioned in later sentences. Is this understand correct?

Comment: @ketan pendharkar - I believe so. However I would have to see the later sentences to be sure. Do you have a link to the text?

Comment: It seems to say that (in the society being described), marriage as we now understand it had been established BUT there is some evidence of earlier practices continuing to exist as well.

Comment: @Kate Bunting - I agree +1. However it could also mean that only the *symbolism* survives, for example in the tales of the gods/heroes.  Otherwise the sentence would have been, "although primitive practices still survived." with no need for the word "symbols"

Comment: @Kate Bunting And this practices are marrage with more than one husband etc which is mantion in next sentences?

Comment: Well, the next two paragraphs mention an invitation to incest, polyandry and [levirate marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levirate_marriage), but they exclude child marriage.

Comment: @Kate Bunting institution of marriage(rules and regulations of marriage) was established though people practice primitive practices such as multi marriage and the like. Am I right? And also here, symbols of primitive practices means old tradition?

Comment: You have never told us what book the extract is from, or what society is being described. I told you in my earlier comment what I _think_ the passage means, from the limited information available. _Primitive practices_ refers to customs from an earlier time when society had fewer rules.

Comment: One source, not the OP’s: https://www.historydiscussion.net/notes/useful-notes-on-the-age-of-the-rig-veda/2136

Comment: @Xanne Thank you. From a quick look through, I agree with Chasly that the 'primitive practices' probably relate to traditional stories rather than the actual customs of the time.